# unable to fast-forward and backward videos with Azure blob

Tags: azure

Uploaded video with azure blob kind storagev2 and video is playing well. But it is not allowing us to fast-forward or backward the videos.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include any code you've written, along with any other details. As written, there's really no question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that Azure does not support byte range requests by default.

There is an explaination of how to enable it here:

https://programmerpayback.com/2013/01/30/hosting-progressive-download-videos-on-azure-blobs/